# What do minzoom and maxzoom do in Mapbox-GL-JS exactly?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, vector-tiles

What exactly do the `minzoom` and `maxzoom` properties on vector tile sources, and vector-based layers do in Mapbox-GL-JS styles? The [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/) is a bit short.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### In a vector tile source

Let's take this example:

```
"mytiles": {
    "type": "vector",
    "tiles": ["http://localhost/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"],
    "minzoom": 7,
    "maxzoom": 12
}
```

This means:

- If there is a TileJSON file available at `http://localhost/tiles/tiles.json` (I think), ignore its `minzoom` and `maxzoom` properties.
- Never attempt to fetch any tile outside the range 7-12.
- If a tile is needed at, say, zoom 13, then fetch the equivalent tile at zoom 12, and overzoom it instead.
- If a tile is needed at, say, zoom, 6, then don't display a tile at all. Underzooming never occurs.

If `minzoom` and/or `maxzoom` properties are not defined on the source, the equivalent properties are used from a TileJSON if available. Otherwise, tiles are assumed to be available at any zoom level requested, and no overzooming occurs. (If tiles aren't actually available, they just don't display.)

### In a vector layer

Let's take this example, referring to the source above:

```
{
    "id": "mylayer",
    "source": "mytiles",
    "source-layer": "mytiles-layer",
    "type": "fill",
    "minzoom": 10,
    "maxzoom": 14
}
```

This means:

- Never display this layer at zooms less than 10, even though there are tiles available.
- Attempt to display this layer at zooms 10.0-13.9, overzooming tiles between 13.0 and 13.9 as required.
- Never display this layer at zooms 14+

If `minzoom`/`maxzoom` properties are not defined, then the layer will attempt to display at any given zoom within the source's zoom range.

### On the map object

For completeness: When instantiating the Map object:

```
   const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
     container: 'map,
     style,
     minZoom: 8, // note the camel-case
     maxZoom: 15
   });
```

This means:

- Don't allow the user to zoom out less than 8, or in more than 15.

Comment: That sounds pretty much it, except the last bit mylayer should display at 13.9 but not 14, at least that's how it works with my testing. map.setZoom(14) hides the layer.